# How to count how many times an event occurred in the last 24 hour of a given date?

Tags: python, pandas, window, rolling-computation

Given a dataframe representing orders with columns: `ID, order_date, expedition_date, ...` I want to assign a new column to the dataframe that contains, for each row, how many orders were placed (i.e., order_date) in the last 24h with respect to the row's expedition_date.

For example: for a row with expedition_date **2022-12-14 10:46:00**, the new calculated field would be the number of rows with order_date between **2022-12-13 10:46:00** and **2022-12-14 10:46:00**.

I can't just use rolling on order_date, as that would return, for each row, how many orders were placed in the last 24h with respect to its own `order_date`, not with respect to its `expedition_date`.

Answer (score 0):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [940, 941, 942, 943, 944, 945, 946],
        "order_date": [
            "2022-12-11 3:52:00",
            "2022-12-13 10:55:00",
            "2022-12-13 14:46:00",
            "2022-12-13 19:10:00",
            "2022-12-15 2:22:00",
            "2022-12-16 19:19:00",
            "2022-12-16 20:02:00",
        ],
        "expedition_date": [
            "2022-12-12 1:01:00",
            "2022-12-14 10:46:00",
            "2022-12-14 10:46:00",
            "2022-12-14 10:46:00",
            "2022-12-15 12:21:00",
            "2022-12-16 5:59:00",
            "2022-12-17 18:29:00",
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it using Pandas [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
for col in ["order_date", "expedition_date"]:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

series = []
i = 0
while i < df.shape[0]:
    tmp = df.copy().loc[:i, :]
    tmp.loc[i, "order_count"] = sum(
        (tmp["order_date"] <= tmp.loc[tmp.shape[0] - 1, "expedition_date"])
        & (
            tmp["order_date"]
            >= tmp.loc[tmp.shape[0] - 1, "expedition_date"] - pd.DateOffset(days=1)
        )
    )
    series.append(tmp.loc[i, :].to_frame().T.astype({"order_count": int}))
    i += 1

new_df = pd.concat(series)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
    id          order_date     expedition_date  order_count
0  940 2022-12-11 03:52:00 2022-12-12 01:01:00            1
1  941 2022-12-13 10:55:00 2022-12-14 10:46:00            1
2  942 2022-12-13 14:46:00 2022-12-14 10:46:00            2
3  943 2022-12-13 19:10:00 2022-12-14 10:46:00            3
4  944 2022-12-15 02:22:00 2022-12-15 12:21:00            1
5  945 2022-12-16 19:19:00 2022-12-16 05:59:00            0
6  946 2022-12-16 20:02:00 2022-12-17 18:29:00            2
```